# Xamarin Forms error with android 13: "Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError" Failed resolution of: Landroidx/concurrent/futures/AbstractResolvableFuture

Tags: xamarin.forms, guava, androidx

This might save someone a little bit of time.

After updating Xamarin Forms to the latest version (5.0.) and the android project to the new aim version 13 (a lot of errors might be gone, just because you the latest version requires Android 13, not 12 not 11 (but it is not well written down)
I got a bunch of problems because of the migration to AndroidX. Using the automatic migration of Visualstudio 2022, could not fix the problems. I still got the Landroidx-Error when trying to build the debug-version:

*"Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError" Failed resolution of: Landroidx/concurrent/futures/AbstractResolvableFuture"*

After some research I updated the all related AndroidX-Legacy-Packages in nuget. But i missed one specific package: Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture. It had the version 9999.0. but the actual version should be 1.0.0.14 +
nuget could not find it automaticaly because of the sorting (9999.0 is higher then 1.0.0.14+)

After the update (downgrade for nuget) I had no problems except the warning that the package is downgraded:
`Warnung    NU1605  Ein Downgrade des Pakets "Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture" von 9999.0.0 auf 1.0.0.14 wurde festgestellt. Verweisen Sie direkt aus dem Projekt auf das Paket, um eine andere Version auszuwählen.  SHAPP.Android -> Xamarin.Google.Guava 31.1.0.8 -> Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture (>= 9999.0.0)  SHAPP.Android -> Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture (>= 1.0.0.14)           1`

might help someone.

just informing if someone has maybe the same problem and would't like to search for years

Answer (score 0):

You can try to uninstall nuget `Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture` from your  app and reinstall this nuget again.

The steps are:

Right click your solution --> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution --> alter to the `Installed`  tab,uninstall nuget `Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture`--> search nuget `Xamarin.Google.Guava.ListenableFuture` and reinstall this nuget to your`Android` project of your solution.

For more information, check document : [Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio).